# Error while running `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Tags: apt

When I run command `sudo apt-get autoclean` I get error message as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/ - opendir (2: No such file or directory)
```

What is this error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 
 `E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/ - opendir (2: No such file or directory)` clearly says "No such file or directory".

So, Try to create the directory, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

Comment: I forgot to check directory's existence. Now error gone.

Comment: That's OK. No worries. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj which dupe? (post link of Q.)

Comment: @AvinashRaj How is that a duplicate?  Care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

When you update your system, packages are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and when the download is not completed, partially downloaded .deb files are moved to `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`

Try to recreate the directory (which usually should be empty) like this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

Then, re-run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the directories exist.

```
 ls /var/cache/apt/
```

If the archives folder does not exist, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
sudo apt-get autoclean
```